# Run shell script from PATH using root

Tags: script, bash, sudo

I have added a shell script to my ~/bin folder.  When I type the script name normally in the terminal it finds the script just fine.  However, when trying to launch the script using the sudo prefix, I get `sudo: apt-get4: command not found`.

Command that works: `apt-get4`

Doesn't work: `sudo apt-get4 update`

Currently the script is owned by the user pi with executable privileges, and I also chmod 777'd.

The script filename is '`apt-get4`'.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`~/bin` is accessible only to the user (here pi), but is not on the path for `root` user.

If you want to run with `sudo` you will need to enter the full path `/home/pi/bin/apt-get4`.

This is not the best way to do things, and is not actually a Pi question.

Comment: I went ahead and added 'sudo' in front of my command inside the shell script. 
Sorry if this isn't the right forum, I asked here in case things were different on the pi vs other Linux distros.

Comment: @moatist Raspbian is a standard Linux Debian distribution; it differs only in the boot process and in having a few Pi specific commands e.g. `gpio` to access the hardware.